# Concatenate list of 1d numpy arrays to 2d numpy

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have object contain list of numpy, like the follow:

```
[array([1, 2, 6]),
 array([1, 2, 7]),
 array([1, 2, 3]),
 array([3, 4, 3]),
 array([5, 6, 9]),
 array([5, 6, 7])]
```

How to build one numpy from them, like the follow?

```
[[1,2,6],
 [1,2,7],
 [1,2,3],
 [3,4,3],
 [5,6,9],
 [5,6,7]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l = [array([1, 2, 6]),
 array([1, 2, 7]),
 array([1, 2, 3]),
 array([3, 4, 3]),
 array([5, 6, 9]),
 array([5, 6, 7])]

np.stack(l)
```

Output -

```
array([[1, 2, 6],
       [1, 2, 7],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 3],
       [5, 6, 9],
       [5, 6, 7]])
```